# Returning Partial View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Hi I have a partial view setup for handling error messages, but when it's returned it returns a full webpage with just the text No Results Found.

I would expect the Partial View to return inline on my main Index page? As in my Index page I have the code `@Html.Partial("_ErrorMessage")`.

Below is how I'm handling this in my HomeController

```
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "No results found!";
                return PartialView("ErrorMessage");
            }
        }
```

Comment: In `@Html.Partial("_ErrorMessage")` contains `_` while `return PartialView("ErrorMessage");` doesn't..

Comment: Need more information, atleast the full action method or how you are calling this method. I assume you are doing a form submit and in else condition you are returning your partial view - if this is the case, the result you see now is the expected behavior. Try calling this action via ajax and append the html returned by this action to your html container

Answer (score 0):

Partial view not necessary return html inline. Partial view can return html inline if you call by client script, using jquery, angular, etc.

This way did you make. The return is a whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Context is important here.  If you are including the partial view in line in the HTML, you  probably don't need to return the partial view in C-sharp unless you're using a fancy asynchronous call to load it.

The in-line partial view should display normally if you just show the view where it was included

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the exactly error you are facing but you can try following solution, you have to set `Layout` as `null` after you will not facing the full page on your partial view.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

If you are not using `Layout=null` it will call your `_Layout` page.

Hope it helps you.